# Sintaxis incorrecta CASE TSQL en SQL server 2014

Tags: sql-server, tsql

Mi problema es el siguiente: Tengo que hacer un script en `TSQL` que haga que si los números son menores de 50 debe hacer la raíz de la suma de sus cuadrados, si es igual a 50 se suman sus cuadrados, y si es mayor que 50 dividir el primero entre el producto de los dos primeros.

He realizado este script:

```
/*Condición si la suma es menor de 50 hacer raíz cuadrada de los cuadrados, si */
DECLARE
    @num smallint;
    SET @num = 30;
DECLARE 
    @num2 smallint;
    SET @num2 = 10;
DECLARE
    @num3 smallint;
    SET @num3 = 10;
DECLARE 
    @raiz decimal (4,3);
DECLARE
    @suma int;
DECLARE
    @cuadrado int;
DECLARE
    @div float;
BEGIN
    SET @suma = @num+@num2+@num3;
    IF (@suma < 50)
        BEGIN
            SET @raiz = sqrt(@num^2+@num2^2+@num3^2);
            print @raiz;
        END
    IF (@suma = 50)
        BEGIN
            SET @cuadrado = @num^2+@num2^2+@num3^2;
            print @cuadrado;
        END
    IF (@suma > 50)
        BEGIN
            SET @div = @num/(@num2*@num3);
            print @div;
        END
END
```

No da error, pero no funciona bien cuando el número es igual a 50, ni cuando mayor, así que he considerado una expresión `case`  :

```
DECLARE
    @num smallint;
    SET @num = 30;
DECLARE 
    @num2 smallint;
    SET @num2 = 10;
DECLARE
    @num3 smallint;
    SET @num3 = 10;
DECLARE 
    @raiz decimal (4,3);
DECLARE
    @suma int;
DECLARE
    @cuadrado int;
DECLARE
    @div float;
SET @suma = @num+@num2+@num3;

CASE
    WHEN(@suma < 50)
        THEN
            SET @raiz = sqrt(@num^2+@num2^2+@num3^2);
            print @raiz;

    WHEN (@suma = 50)
        THEN
            SET @cuadrado = @num^2+@num2^2+@num3^2;
            print @cuadrado;

    ELSE (@suma > 50)
        THEN
            SET @div = @num/(@num2*@num3);
            print @div;
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero que todo, una expresión `CASE` no es un bucle, es simplemente una expresión que entrega un resultado.

Lo que necesitas es bastante simple:

```
DECLARE @num smallint, @num2 smallint, @num3 smallint;

SET @num = 30;
SET @num2 = 10;
SET @num3 = 10;

DECLARE @suma int;
SET @suma = @num+@num2+@num3;

SELECT  CASE 
            WHEN @suma < 50 THEN sqrt(@num^2+@num2^2+@num3^2)
            WHEN @suma = 50 THEN @num^2+@num2^2+@num3^2
            WHEN @suma > 50 THEN CAST(@num as float)/(@num2*@num3)
        END
```

Comment: Gracias, era un fallo de concepto bastante importante